# Can number of javascript files make project slower or any effects?

Tags: javascript, html, client-side

I am working on a project using HTML and JavaScript. I am using a number of JavaScript files in my project. I want to know if there are any side-effects caused by the number of JavaScript files in a web project? (In terms of efficiency or speed).

Answer (score 4):

> I want to know that Is there any effect of no of JavaScript files in a web project ? In terms of efficiency or speed.

If you mean, is there a speed cost associated with having all of your JavaScript embedded in inline `script` tags within your HTML, then maybe, maybe not; it depends on how much JavaScript there is.

It's a trade-off:

- If you put all of your JavaScript in the HTML files, that means you have to duplicate it in each HTML file, making each one larger. If it's a lot of script, that adds up to each HTML file being heavier, and it means when you change the *content* (rather than the code), you force the user to re-download all of that code.
- If you put your JavaScript in a separate file, you have an additional HTTP request when your page is loaded, but only if the JavaScript file isn't already in cache — and all of your HTML files are that much smaller.

So in most cases, if you have any significant amount of code, you're better off using a separate JavaScript file and setting the caching headers correctly so that the browser doesn't need to send the separate HTTP request each time. For instance, configure your server to tell the browser that JavaScript file is good for a long time, so it doesn't even do an `If-Modified-Since` HTTP request. Then if you need to update your JavaScript, change the filename and refer to the new file in your HTML.

That's just *one* approach to caching control, which is a significant and non-trival topic. But you get the idea. Making it separate gives you options like that, with a fairly low initial cost (the one extra HTTP request to load it into cache). But it can be overkill for a quite small amount of code.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of execution, I believe there should be no considerable difference depending on the number of JavaScript-files you have. However, a large number of JavaScript-files require a large number of requests when your page is loaded, which definitely may impact the time it takes to load your page.

There are at least two ways to handle this and which approach to use depends on the situation at hand.

**Bundle all files into one:**

Each request to the server adds to the time it takes to load your page. Becuse of this it is often considered good practice to bundle and minify your JavaScript-files into one single file, containing all your scripts, thus requiring only a single request to load all the JavaScript.

In some cases however, if you have very much JavaScript for instance, that single file can become quite large, and even if you just load a single file, loading that file may take some time, thus slowing down your page load. In that case, it might be worth considering option two.

**Load modules as you need them:**

In other cases, for example if you have a lot of JavaScript for your site, but only a few modules of all your code is used on each page, it might give you better performance to use conditional loading. In that case, you keep your code in separate modules and have each module in a separate file. You can then load only the modules you need on each page.

Comment: Depending on the use case, loading all JavaScript upfront can also have a very negative impact. It is totally dependent on the use case whether to use a single packaged file or individual modules that are loaded when needed. Minimization is very useful indeed, but logical separation into modules makes a lot of sense in most cases.

Comment: @TorstenWalter I agree, there are situations where it might be better to load the modules as you need them. I'll clarify my answer somewhat.

Comment: @TorstenWalter It's indeed depending on the use case. Nice arguments and tips.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend entirely on the javascript files that you will include. Naturally, when including a javascript file, it will have to be loaded by the browser. How taxing this is depends on the size of the file. Generally speaking it is advantageous to minimize the number of separate requests of script files by combining all code in a single file

Answer (score 0):

A larger number of JavaScript files can cause your page to load slower, but if everything caches correctly their shouldn't be any problem. A browser that requests a lot of files from cache is a bit slower before rendering, but we are talking about 0.001 seconds.

In Crowders post if you are correctly caching then you have to change your filename and refer to it, but if you implement a nice caching mechanism in your webproject it's easier to refer your JavaScript with a querystring like:

```
scripts/foo.js?version=1
```

We use the software versionnumber, so every new release we change the querystring and all clients get the new script files.

Everytime you release it's best to bundle en minify all of your JavaScript, but it isn't that useful for small projects.